# rotating images used as backgrounds with 100% width and height

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I have rotating background images that expand/contract if the browser window is expanded/contracted?

Does anyone know a script that does this? Or would there be a way with just CSS?

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin called SuperSized: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ and the plugin handles all cross browser compatibility for you and will swap images at the time interval of your choosing if you want.

Or, the HTML5 way to do this (only supported in some browsers like Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vzYrf/

```
html {
        background: url(http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-XL.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Or two more ways to do it yourself: [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: Does anyone recommend something else?

Comment: How does this work? I downloaded it and saved it in the same path or folder as my website is saved on but how do I activate it? It's just a file thats there... New to jQuery, so confused lol.

Comment: You include it and jQuery in your page to get the code in your page and then follow the instructions for using the full screen background slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple :)

some css:

```
<style type="text/css">
   html { height: 100%; overflow:hidden;}
   body { background-color: transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border-top: 1px transparent solid; margin-top: -1px; z-index:0; position:relative; }
   img#background { height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: -1; position:absolute; color: black; }
</style>
```

you can play with these values ...

and body content:

```
<body bgcolor="#000300" style="margin:0px; width:100%">
 <img id="background" src="background.jpg" alt="My Background" />
</body>
```

this is for 1 background, the rest you can do with javascript ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeBackground(){
      var backgrounds = ['back1.jpg', 'back2.jpg', 'back3.jpg'];
      var inRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgrounds.length);
      document.getElementById('background').src = backgrounds[inRandom];
      setTimeout ( "changeBackground()", 10000 );
   }
   setTimeout ( "changeBackground()", 10000 );
</script>
```

I didn't test the script, but this is basically the idea ...